# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. at

Tags: c#, sql, insert, oledb

I have a problem while attempting to insert values into a table in my asp.net web application. I keep getting the error
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. at...
I'm not sure why, I'm hoping its just a typo. But here is my Datalayer class code:

```
public void RegisterUser(string username, string city, string state, string favLang, string leastFavLang, string date, string password)
{      
    dbConnection.Open();
    string sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO tblUserInfo (Username, City, State, FavoriteLanguage, LeastFavoriteLanguage, lastComplete, Password)";
   // sqlStmt += "VALUES (" + username + ", " + city + ", " + state + ", " + favLang + ", " + leastFavLang + ", " + date + ", " + password + ")";
    sqlStmt += " VALUES (@username, @city, @state, @favLang, @leastFavLang, @compDate, @password)";
   OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlStmt, dbConnection);
    OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter("@username", username);
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);        
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@city",city));
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@state",state));
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@favLang",favLang));
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@leastFavLang",leastFavLang));
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@compDate",date));
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@password",password));
     dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

And here is the c# behind the page:

```
protected void AddToDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bool userAddError = false;
    string tempPath = Server.MapPath("Programaholics.accdb");
    clsDataLayer myDataLayer = new clsDataLayer(tempPath);
    try
    {
        myDataLayer.RegisterUser(lblUsername.Text, lblCity.Text, lblState.Text, lblFavLang.Text, lblLeastFavLang.Text, lblDate.Text,lblpass.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        userAddError = true;
        string message = "Error.";
       Master.MasterLabel.Text = message + "" + error;
    }
    if (!userAddError)
    {
        Master.MasterLabel.Text = "User added";
    }
}
```

yes, it is a project for school I've already written the code I just need help troubleshooting why it wont work.

Comment: This is a common error. Password is a reserved keyword. You need to put that word between square brackets [Password]

Comment: Never, ever store passwords as plain text - hash them

Comment: @steve I need to change which password? would it just be better to change them all to "pass"?  thank you I would never do that in any real life situation. It was one of my troubleshooting attempts to see if the pass being hashed was what was the problem. Thank you for the quick answers.

Comment: You have a field named 'Password'. This creates the problem because when you use it in your queries the database engine parser will be confused by that word. To help it work correctly, you put the incriminating word between square brackets or you change that field name in your database table.

Comment: @Steve got it, changed from old, and now it's     string sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO tblUserInfo (Username, City, State, FavoriteLanguage, LeastFavoriteLanguage, lastComplete, [Password])";